# Position Dependent Custom Syntax Error Checking

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype, syntax

I am trying to design a custom syntax file that performs some basic error checking for an ascii input file.  The input is broken up into sections, and there are input cards specific to each section.  The input cards vary and can have either a single argument or multiple.  A brief example of the cards with valid input is:

```
{FOO}
  card1  100.0       !%
  card2  559.0    A  ![ABC]
{BAR}
```

The goal is to have the following input cards have bad arguments, the syntax flips to highlight the errors for the first card1 argument which needs to be positive, and highlights the second card2 argument Z which needs to be either A, B, or C:

```
{FOO}
  card1  -100.0       !%
  card2  100.0    Z  ![ABC]
{BAR}
```

Here is what my current syntax file looks like for the above example:

```
syn match   testComment "\s*!.*$"
syn region testFOOBlockRegion start="^\{FOO\}" end="^\{"re=e-1,he=e-1,me=e-1 contains=testComment,testFOOCards,testFOOBlockName keepend
syn region testFOOBlockName start="^\{FOO" end="\}" contained oneline

syn match testChar "\s[ABC]\{1}" contained

" Floating point number with decimal no E or e
syn match testFloat "\s[-+]\=\d\+\.\=\d*"
syn match testFloat "/[^=]\+d\+\.\=\d*"
syn match testPosFloat "\s[+]\=\d\+\.\=\d*" contained
syn match testNegFloat "\s[-]\{1}\d\+\.\=\d*" contained

" Floating point like number with E and decimal point (+,-)
syn match testFloat "\s[-+]\=\d*\.\=\d*[eE][\-+]\=\d\+"
syn match testPosFloat "\s[+]\=\d*\.\=\d*[eE][\-+]\=\d\+" contained
syn match testNegFloat "\s[-]\{1}\d*\.\=\d*[eE][\-+]\=\d\+" contained

"Arbitrary regions for cards
syn region testSecondArgPosFloat  start="\s*\S\+\s\+"rs=e,ms=e,hs=e end="\S\+" contains=testPosFloat keepend contained
syn region testThirdArgChar  start="\s*\S\+\s\+\S\+\s\+"rs=e,ms=e,hs=e end="\S\+" contains=testChar keepend contained

"The semi-colon is for multiple cards on one line.
syn region testFOOCards  start="\s*card1" end=";\|$" contains=testComment,testSecondArgPosFloat  keepend contained
syn region testFOOCards  start="\s*card2" end=";\|$" contains=testComment,testSecondArgPosFloat,testThirdArgChar  keepend contained

"Assign syntax groups
hi def link testFloat                   Number
hi def link testPosFloat                Number
hi def link testNegFloat                Number
hi def link testChar                    Todo
hi def link testComment                 Comment
hi def link testFOOBlockName            Conditional
hi def link testFOOCards                Identifier
"Assign these groups to the Error group.  
"In this way, a correct match will cause the syntax to highlight the characters as defined above, 
"and a bad match will indicate an error.
"  If the third argument isn't a char from the list, error
hi def link testThirdArgChar            Error
  "If the second argument isn't a positive float, error
hi def link testSecondArgPosFloat       Error
  "This ensures that only valid cards are syntaxed correctly and other cards are highlighted as errors
hi def link testFOOBlockRegion          Error
```

Essentially, with the current syntax, I am able to get a card with a single argument behaving and highlighting properly.  If card1 has a negative sign placed infront of it, the syntax highlighting changes to the error syntax.  For card2, only the first argument's syntax works, the second does not.  I believe it is an issue with the `keepend` option where the syntax reverts after the "second argument" is matched, regardless of it being correct or an error, to the syntax for `testFOOCards`.

I'm afraid that the only way to get this to work is to have multiple nested permutations of things like `SecondArgFloatWithThirdArgChar` regions and was wondering if anyone else had something more simple/elegant or knew where else I could be looking in the manual.  Thanks in advance.

### Update

Several tests using the `nextgroup` suggestion that were tried were:

1. ```
   syn region testSecondArgPosFloat 
   start="\s*\S\+\s\+"rs=e,ms=e,hs=e end="\S\+"
   nextgroup=testThirdArgTempUnit contains=testPosFloat keepend
   contained
   ```
2. ```
   syn region testFOOCards  start="\s*card2" end=";\|$" 
   nextgroup=testSecondArgPosFloat 
   contains=testComment,testSecondArgPosFloat,testThirdArgTempUnit 
   keepend contained
   ```
3. ```
   syn region testSecondArgPosFloat 
   start="\s*\S\+\s\+"rs=e,ms=e,hs=e end="\S\+"
   nextgroup=testThirdArgTempUnit contains=testPosFloat
   contained
   ```
4. ```
   syn region testFOOCards  start="\s*card2" end=";\|$" 
   nextgroup=testSecondArgPosFloat 
   contains=testComment,testSecondArgPosFloat,testThirdArgTempUnit 
   contained
   ```

It would seem that the `nextgroup` argument doesn't solve the problem.  There was only a noticeable syntax change when the `keepend` option was toggled.

Since this current version uses regions to march forward across the line from left to right, I tried using `syn match` to match the third argument first, use `nextgroup` to match the second argument, and lastly a match for `card2`.  That also did not work as I'd like.

I was also curious if defining the starting region in the examples above changed where subsequent matches would be found. I tested this by adding more floats between the first and second argument values in `card2` to see if the highlighting would change to what I expected.  That also did not work.  I also tried using `^` in `start` match to anchor it to the beginning of the line, and repeated adding arguments.  That didn't work either.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Do you think [`nextgroup=`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-nextgroup) would help here? You could use it to specify which groups to use to match the following field... Right?

Comment: @filbranden I added an update trying out your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after playing around with all sorts of options starting with `nextgroup=`, I found a solution.  The issue was a combination of using the `rs=,ms=` and needing to nest successive arguments in the contains block.

The original example:

```
"Arbitrary regions for cards
syn region testSecondArgPosFloat  start="\s*\S\+\s\+"rs=e,ms=e,hs=e end="\S\+" contains=testPosFloat keepend contained
syn region testThirdArgChar       start="\s*\S\+\s\+\S\+\s\+"rs=e,ms=e,hs=e end="\S\+" contains=testChar keepend contained
```

becomes:

```
"Arbitrary regions for cards
syn region testSecondArgPosFloat  start="\s*\S\+\s\+"hs=e end="\S\+" contains=testPosFloat keepend contained
syn region testThirdArgChar       start="\s*\S\+\s\+\S\+\s\+"hs=e end="\S\+" contains=testChar,testSecondArgPosFloat keepend contained
```

Also, there isn't a need to specify more `contains=` matches than necessary for the cards.  Since the `testThirdArgChar` contains the second argument for a positive float, it doesn't need to be listed for the card.

The original card2:

```
syn region testFOOCards  start="\s*card2" end=";\|$" contains=testComment,testSecondArgPosFloat,testThirdArgTempUnit contained
```

becomes:

```
syn region testFOOCards  start="\s*card2" end=";\|$" contains=testComment,testThirdArgTempUnit contained
```

While this solution may not be the most efficient, it does behave how I want for 90% of the cases.  I currently can't get the error highlighting to work if there are two cards on the same line when the `;` is used, but that can be deferred for now.